# update tar archive in the relative directory

Tags: directory, tar, update

when I want to create a tar archive in a relative path, I can do this:

```sh
tar cf archiveName.tar -C relative/path  someDirectory
```

but when I want to update the archive, this

```
tar uf archiveName.tar -C relative/path someDirectory
```

gives me the following errors:

```
tar: someDirectory/someFile: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
... (same error for all files and dirs in someDirectory)
tar: Exiting with faliure...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running both of these configs in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes, I'm executing them in the same dir. Also, there should be no difference in where I put the actual archiveName.tar (it can be anywhere). I have just tried it again, to be sure: added some files touch someDirectory/{1,2,3} and tried tar uf archiveName... and it broke again.

Answer (score 0):

Although the man page of GNU tar doesn't mentioned, I wonder that `-C` option only works with `c (create)` or `r (replace)` operations.

Unix man page wrote:

> -C directory file
>   Performs a chdir (see cd(1)) operation on directory
>   and performs the c (create) or r (replace) operation on file . Use
>   short relative path names for file . If file is `.', archive all files
>   in directory. This option enables archiving files from multiple
>   directories not related by a close common parent.

So, you can use `r (replace)` option instead:

```
tar rf archiveName.tar -C relative/path someDirectory
```

Comment: This works, but it executes over all files, regardless of their modification time. The goal is to update an archive in some directory (from outside of this dir) so that the full PATH is not given to the archive (using the -C) command. If I do "tar rf", it adds both the old files and the new ones again. I want to use the update in order to skip adding unchanged (old) files to the archive. It seems that "-C" doesn't work with "u" at all...